# How to add more than one button in Border Layout

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

This is the Picture of Border Layout 
[image]

I want to add Three buttons at Page_End. is it possible ? and how ?

Note:I cant change layout. else i have to change so much code.

Comment: Take a close look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Add a JPanel (or Panel) on PAGE_END
- Use some layout on it (again BorderLayout for example).
- Add some other components (like buttons) on that JPanel.

** Sample code as requested **

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton button1 = new JButton("Bottom Left");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Bottom Right");
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(button1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
panel.add(button2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

pane.add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```